# More issues with WIFI Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260: networks detected but not connecting

Tags: debian, wifi

Debian 10 Buster

It looks there are a bunch of topics on WIFI Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 and I went over them and still, I couldn't figure out my problem.

My Wifi connection was good. Then I played with the configuration to learn using nmcli and other tools and all went wrong. Now my network manager detects WIFI networks but is not connecting.
I am connected to an ethernet port now from a hotspot.

Network-manager and network-manager-gnome seems to be running
Firmware looks is there:

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    8.290464] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.354030] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode
[    8.354519] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 38.755cfdd8.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    8.456600] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9260, REV=0x324
[    8.505714] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: base HW address: (i removed the numbers)
[    8.608357] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
sudo uname -r
4.19.0-12-amd64
```

I tried to remove firmware-iwlwifi, reinstall. NO effect.
I reinstalled network-manager. No effect.
I have no idea what is going on. Any help?thanks

**[edit] Some more clues**
I found where this seems to be failing but I have not found the fix.

```
:~$ nmcli dev status
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
eno1    ethernet  connected     eno1       
wlp4s0  wifi      disconnected  --         
lo      loopback  unmanaged     --
```

The device wlp4s0 is disconnected
I search how to connect, not clear, but I tried:

```
:~$ sudo nmcli dev connect wlp4s0
Error: Failed to add/activate new connection: A 'wireless' setting is required if no AP path was given.
```

So, it looks to me that if I can fix the "'wireless' setting" and connect wlp4s0 the problem may be fixed.

So, what are these settings and how to change them?

Comment: You likely wiped out your corresponding profile configurations. When you use `nmcli dev connect wlp4s0` , network manager is only being told a starting point, i.e. use this partifuclar WIFI device to connect, but you never told it where to connect to (or how, i.e. password etc). There needs to be a preexisting connection profile (previously made and authenitcated connection, with preexisting settings) otherwise `nmcli` won't know where to go. See the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that some settings were wrong in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and after rebooting, all good.

Comment: Could you tell us what settings those were?

Answer (score 2):

First, you should check if your adapter can find your AP with

```
nmcli d wifi list

*  SSID             MODE   CHAN  RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY
   [YOUR_SSID]      Infra   1   54 Mbit/s     99
```

If you cannot see your AP, then make sure your radio is on with

```
nmcli r wifi on
```

Once your AP is visible all you should have to do is:

```
nmcli d wifi connect [YOUR_SSID] password [your wifi password] ifname wlp4s0
```

Finally, once you connect, the connection profile should be added and visible among those displayed by:

```
nmcli c show
```